# Creational Pattern for creating or returning an object from other objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

A problem I've come across and never really had a good answer for, is: what is the correct design pattern for creating or returning an object from another object, or multiple objects?

Traditionally I've just created a `Factory` and had the source as a argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
class Foo {
    String bar
}

class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo(Map mapWithBar) {
        Foo foo = new Foo()
        foo.bar = mapWithBar.get('bar')
        foo
    }
}

assert 'Hello, World!' == new FooFactory().createFoo(['bar': 'Hello, World!']).bar
```

Is factory really the correct name for this pattern?

What happens when you want to encapsulate pseudo-creational logic that has multiple possible sources, or possibly the object is even already created?

For example, say if `bar` is in a `list of Strings` (i.e. cli args), set `bar` from that, otherwise if `Foo` already exists in some data structure, use that `foo`, otherwise create a new `Foo` with a default `bar`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
class Foo {
    String bar
}

class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo(List<String> args, Map mapContainingFoo, String defaultBar) {
        if (args?.size > 0) {
            def foo = new Foo();
            foo.bar = args[0];
            return foo;
        } else if (mapContainingFoo?.containsKey('foo')) {
            return mapContainingFoo.get('foo');
        } else {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.bar = defaultBar;
            return foo;
        }
    }
}

def fooFactory = new FooFactory();
assert 'args' == fooFactory.createFoo(['args'], ['foo': new Foo(bar: 'fromMap')], 'default').bar
assert 'fromMap' == fooFactory.createFoo(null, ['foo': new Foo(bar: 'fromMap')], 'default').bar
assert 'default' == fooFactory.createFoo(null, null, 'default').bar
```

Is there a better design pattern to encapsulate this logic? Is `Factory` the correct term? Is it even still a `Factory` since it isn't necessarily creating `Foo`?

Note that I'm only using groovy for ease of demonstration, I'm mainly concerned with the design pattern and not an idiomatic way of doing this in groovy.

Answer (score 2):

Rest easy, `Factory` is the correct pattern/term.

One of many examples is: the AppFabric cache product has a DataCacheFactory class. The factory might new() up underlying objects establishing connectivity to the cache server; or utilize existing connected objects.

Answer (score 1):

You did well choosing Factory pattern and the implementation seem fine to me (IMHO).

> What happens when you want to encapsulate pseudo-creational logic that
>   has multiple possible sources, or possibly the object is even already
>   created?

As you know, *Factory pattern* hides the creation logic so that you don't have to repeat such logic all over the project. If the logic is too simple or too complex depends on the design (and this last depends on the requirements). In any case, the thing is to provide the responsability to the specific component/s.

> Is it even still a Factory since it isn't necessarily creating Foo?

Yes, it's. Look at it from the point of view of the client (Factory consumer). You would be just providing the arguments in order to get a new Foo. That's it. What's going on under the hood is not your business.

Back to the example. I would suggest you some changes.

```
class Foo {
    String bar       
}

class FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo(List<String> args, Map mapContainingFoo, String defaultBar) {
        if (mapContainingFoo?.containsKey('foo')) {
            return mapContainingFoo.get('foo').clone();
        }
        def foo =new Foo();
        foo.bar = defaultBar;

        if (args?.size > 0) { 
            foo.bar = args[0];
        } 
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I guess it's a sample code, nevertheless, I have reordered the if-else block. If that  matters.

The change that matters (IMO) is:

```
//If foo is not clonable, make a copy.
mapContainingFoo.get('foo').clone();
```

The reason is simple. When I call a Factory I expect a new brand object, untied from the input params.